# De moivre's theorem based problem

Tags: complex-analysis

How to solve this type of problems

As $(cosx + i sinx)^n =cos(nx) + i sin(nx)$ if *n* is an integer or rational.

If power is irrational then how to simplify.

Also we know that $i = cos \frac {π}{2} + i sin \frac {π}{2}  $.

So how to use it.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAJts.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! You are suggested to type in what your question is and show your attempt. Follow this link for MathJax Reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The answer should be **1** is not it?

Comment: I don't know that answer is 1. If it is 1 then I'm unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are acquainted with few definition or properties of complex exponential and logarithms the given expression simplifies to $\large i^i$ the modulus of such is 1.

Comment: Is the answer correct?

Comment: I know the few properties of logarithm and complex exponential. By these properties, I write i^e^-π/2 =(e^e^-π/2)log(i)=(e^e^-π/2)[log|i| +iarg(i)]=(e^e^-π/2)[0+i(π/2 +2nπ)] so that |z|=(e^e^-π/2)(π/2+2nπ)

Comment: Ohh yes , I made a mistake in above comment

Comment: It should be z= e^(e^-π/2)i(π/2 +2nπ) so that |z|=1. Is this correct?